# Select only one side of a text frame in InDesign CS6

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6, selections

I am designing a fillable form in InDesign CS6 (Mac) and want to add a border to only the bottom of certain text frames. My question is: how do I select only one side of a text frame?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the white arrow – the [direct selection tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/selecting-objects.html) – you can select the bottom vertexes of your rectangle; but that won't do you any good. The border of a frame in InDesign is applied to the entire frame, not on a per-selection basis (just like in Illustrator).

Some other options:

1. Put your text inside a one-cell table. Each of a cell's borders *can* have a setting of its own.
2. Set a Rule Below for the last paragraph in this frame.
3. Draw a line manually, and either leave it placed on your page (so it will not move vertically when you add or remove text), or cut it and paste as an anchored object on the last text line (and then it will move along with the text).

Since a fillable form needs to be of a fixed size anyway, I'd simply draw a horizontal line just below it.

Comment: I second the one-cell table. ID's tables are remarkably good for layout purposes.

Comment: I chose to use option #3, mostly because it was most familiar to me. I will look into the one-cell table option later as time permits.  Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Object → Effects → Inner Shadow → Mode: normal, X Offset: 0, Size: 0; Y offset: border width.

Comment: Just tried exactly this on a text object in ID / CS5.5 and it didn't work for me. Ended up drawing a line.

Comment: I tried this for a vertical ruler on the left side. This does seem to work on-screen, but printers (including pdf printers) may leave a very thin line in the shadow colour on the top and / or the bottom of the object.